# Working with group_by on a created_at field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, group-by

I'm sorry I couldn't find a lighter title for what I come up with.

The thing is I need to group some stuff by date, but not time. That's to say I want them grouped by days, problem comes when grouping by created_at field, because it gets to seconds precision:

```
@stuff = SomeCoolStuff.where(cool_guy_id: @guy.id).group_by(&:created_at)
```

This gives me this kind of key for the hash: `2012-10-02 08:16:13 +0200`, but what I want in the keys is only `2012-10-02`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figured it out myself, for whoever may be interested this is the way I eneded up with:

```
@stuff = SomeCoolStuff.where(cool_guy_id: @guy.id).group_by { |stuff| stuff.created_at.to_date }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try format in `config/locales/en.yml` like this:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
```